# Does Marshal.Release() have an implicit ReliabilityContract?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, com, safehandle

I am writing a .NET application where I have to use API calls (really). My application gets COM interfaces by calling Win API's function `CoCreateInstance()`.

Of course, I have to release those interfaces when having finished with them. I think that the appropriate method to do so is `Marshal.Release()` (at least, no other reasonable method comes to my mind).

Now, I would like to make every respective interface pointer a safe handle. To do that, I have to derive my own safe handle class from `SafeHandle` and have to override `ReleaseHandle()` in the derived class. The [respective documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.releasehandle(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> [...] In particular, apply the ReliabilityContractAttribute attribute
>   to any methods you call from ReleaseHandle. In most cases this code
>   should be: ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState,
>   Cer.Success) [...]

This is my problem: I do not know if `Marshal.ReleaseHandle()` already has this contract by default, and if not, how I could add it. I think I am lacking some basics here. Could somebody out there please shed some light on it?

Comment: Windows API's uses the Window Allocation method and memory will be released based on Windows rules not Net Library rules.  Only Win APIs that hold memory need to be released using a Windows method.

Comment: While this might be true, I think that it does not apply to the situation here. There is a special situation with COM interfaces. My question relates to getting and releasing COM interfaces (basically meaning increasing and decreasing their reference counters), not to allocating or freeing memory regions. As a side note, you might be aware that COM objects *on their own destroy themselves* if the reference counters for all of their interfaces has reached zero (this has nothing to do with my question, though).

Comment: Would simply checking the code answer this?  The abstract method has the attribute [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]

Comment: @Will Great, you have answered exactly my question - sometimes I am a moron. If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it. I have read the implementation of `SafeHandle` all the time at ReferenceSource, but obviously did not come to the idea to read the implementation of `Marshal` as well ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the abstract method `Marshal.Release` is

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated_required
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
public static extern int /* ULONG */ Release(IntPtr /* IUnknown */ pUnk );
```

So it is already decorated with the ReliabilityContractAttribute.  You can check the source of any framework type by using a decompiler (I used JustDecompile) or over at [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Accepting the answer, although you probably wanted to show the code of `Marshal.Release()` (instead of `SafeHandle.ReleaseHandle()`) :-)

Comment: @Binarus Hah!  I got turned around, yes.  Updated.